# No artifacts found that match the file pattern in jenkins configuraion

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifact-deployer

I have a .net class library and configuring that library to the Jenkins. I want to copy the new build dll to the bin directory of the my workplace (F:/Projects/Utility/bin/Release). I have mentioned the path of "Files to archive" to F:/Projects/Utility/bin/Release/*.dll. But as soon as I build through the Jenkins it shows the below error:

> Archiving artifacts
>   ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "F:/Pankaj/Projects/MA/MA Code/Jenkins Code/MA/SEIManagedAccounts/SEI.ManagedAccounts.Utility/bin/Release/*.dll". Configuration error?
>   ERROR: ‘F:/Projects/Utility/bin/Release/*.dll’ doesn’t match anything: even ‘F:’ doesn’t exist
>   Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: "even ‘F:’ doesn’t exist" - isn't that clear enough?

Comment: No. I have the same folder with same path. I have just copied the project bin directory path.

Comment: Where is Jenkins running? On the same machine? That's a bad setup. Is it running as a service? If no, that's a bad setup. If yes, under what account is it running? Is F a local disc on that machine? If it is a network drive, can Jenkins' account access it?